# Where can I find the AngularJS changelog?

Tags: angularjs

It must be in an obvious place but I've net been able to find it. Can someone tell me where it is ?  Is this a link on the main page?  Seems like something that would be perfect to add to the blog.

Comment: you can usually find a CHANGELOG file in the github repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [quick google](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=i0ITU9zUFaGF8QeUyoCoDQ&gws_rd=cr#q=angular.js%20changelog&safe=off) turned up this link to their github repo: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks. I hope someone thinks to add this to them main page. Isn't this one of the most useful undocumented documentation links ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the changelog hosted on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks. Do you think this is something that should go into the blog. Just asking as it seems very very useful and it would be a 5 minute job to add to the blog.